# i am trying to send ether to a list of addresses from backend

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix

Below are few lines from the contract in which I am basically trying to send some ether to an array of addresses. Now, when can run this code in remix solidity by replacing "value" to "msg.value". But I am trying to achieve this from backend.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract init {
    address owner;
    address[] public userAddresses;
    function init() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getaddresses(address rec) public {
        userAddresses.push(rec);
    } 

    function seneth(uint value) public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
            userAddresses[i].transfer(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code that I am trying

```
var txOptions = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(800000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(20000000000),
    to: contractAddress
}

var rawTx = txutils.functionTx(interface, 'seneth', [100000000000000], txOptions);
sendRaw(rawTx);
```

I am running the code in my console but I am getting the output below

[image: attached is the output in etherscan]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the values on array instead of single address in transfer method. It will save the Gas Amount.

Comment: you mean changing the line from "userAddresses[i].transfer(value);"  to "userAddresses.transfer(value);" and removing the for loop?? i have tried but didn't worked out. i have updated the question with the complete code

Answer (score 0):

> Just remove `uint value` from `seneth` function as below because your code says
>   that you are transferring just uint numbers to all addresses instead
>   of sending `msg.value(ethers)`.

Changes in smartcontract :

```
   function seneth () public{
        for (uint i=0; i<userAddresses.length; i++) {

                 userAddresses[i].transfer(msg.value);

      }
    }
```

Changes in web3.js code just add value part:

```
var txOptions = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(800000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(20000000000),
    to: contractAddress
    value: web3.toHex(web3.toBigNumber(10000000000000000))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i concern you are trying to fire multiple transaction called "seneth"  which has functionality to give ether. but you must be careful when you're trying to firing multiple at once there is following exception such as:
1. a fired transaction should be waiting for 30 seconds or less to be completed receive by blockchain network.
2. you can only send another transaction after the current transaction is fully completed if it's not, the interface would recognize the latest transaction as replacement for advance transaction and throw an error "error replacement transaction is underpriced "
3. or it will throw an error caused by nonce too low. it occurs because previous transaction is not yet confirmed and there is already another transaction sent by the same address

Hopefully it helps you!